# mmssms.db is missing/not available

Tags: android, sms

I can not view the mmssms.db (Android/data/com.android.providers.telephony) in my android 4.2 version. I do have root permission (allowed unknown resources from phone settings) but still its not visible.

Can you please explain where it is located ? I searched mmssms.db in entire phone but no use.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uriSMURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor result = getContentResolver().query(uriSMURI, null, null, null, null);
```

The messages are saved in /inbox

Edit: Are you trying to get them from programming or just using your phone? If you are not programming this isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for reply Friar. I want to get it from phone so I can then learn the structure of db. Where should I place my question then ?

Comment: Oh you just want to know the structure of the DB. I'm not sure how you would get that exactly, or where to ask that. It would more than likely be something like (_id, recipient, message, date(?)), but I couldn't say that for sure.

Comment: Any chance you know the path.? I can not view it at Android/data/com.android.providers.telephony

Comment: All I know is the Uri which is linked above.